# Generate uniform random number in range of floats in bash

Tags: bash

## **[SOLVED]**

I want to generate a uniform random float number in the range of float numbers in the bash script. range e.g. [3.556,6.563]

basically, I am creating LSH(Latin hypercube sampling) function in bash. There I would like to generate an array as one can do with this python command line.

`p = np.random.uniform(low=l_lim, high=u_lim, size=[n])`.

sample code :

```
lhs(){

    l_lim=($(seq $1 $2 $(echo $3 - $dif | bc)))
    h_lim=($(seq $(echo $1 + $dif | bc) $2 $3))
    points=()
    for ((i=0;i<$n;i++)) ; do 
        di=${l_lim[i]}
        dj=${h_lim[i]}
        echo $di, $dj
        p=$(awk -v min=6.50 -v max=8.45 -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed);print min+rand()*int(1000*(max-min)+1)/1000}')
        points+=("${p}")
    done
    
}

n=5
a=(3 5)
b=(1 3)
dif=$(div $(echo ${a[1]} - ${a[0]} | bc) $n)

lhs ${a[0]} 0.45 ${a[1]}
echo ${points[@]}
```

I have tried `$RANDOM`, `awk` but it did not work for me. I do not want to use `python -c`.

Comment: Please show us _how_ you tried to use awk, and exactly how it failed -- it's very much the best tool for the job.

Comment: By the way -- `export` should be only used when you have a specific reason to create an environment variable rather than a regular shell variable; and `array=( $(anything) )` is an antipattern; see [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29). Consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: ` would like to replicate the python command line .. np.random.uniform ..` I believe that is close to beeing too broad for a stackoverflow question. Or impossible, as I see in numpy sources, it manipulates in C source file internal float representation. That's not possible in bash.

Comment: Yeah, @CharlesDuffy I have used it because I wanted to use `python -c` but I do not have a python package where I want to run script. So i understand that it is unnecessary. Thanks for remark.

Comment: I asked for an example of how you tried to use awk, not how you tried to use Python.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `$ awk -v min=$di -v max=$dj  'BEGIN{srand(); for (i=1;i<=num;i++) print min+rand()*int(1000*(max-min)+1)/1000}' ` but it generates same number every time.

Comment: Okay, great. The problem there is one of needing to seed the RNG; that's easily fixed. Would you consider editing that awk code into the question?

Comment: ...not just "easily fixed", but it's a duplicate; see [random number generation with awk in bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048378/random-numbers-generation-with-awk-in-bash-shell) -- the approach of using the shell's `RANDOM` to seed awk's rng is exactly what I was going to suggest here.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/Zo97aO showing your above awk code corrected as described in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy It worked for me.   Solution : `p=$(awk -v min=$di -v max=$dj -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed);print min+rand()*int(1000*(max-min)+1)/1000}')`

Comment: BTW, if you're going to need a lot of randomly-generated numbers in the same range, consider getting them all from one copy of awk, instead of restarting awk over and over. For example, you could run `exec {rng_fd}< <(awk ...)` with awk code that creates an infinite stream, then `read num <&$rng_fd` whenever you want another number from that stream, and `exec {rng_fd}<&-` to close the stream when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common `rand()` implementations at least generate a number in the range `[0...1)`, which is really all you need.  You can scale a random number in one range to a number in another using the techniques outlined in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio), eg:

> NewValue = (((OldValue - OldMin) * (NewMax - NewMin)) / (OldMax - OldMin)) + NewMin

For bash you have two choices: integer arithmetic or use a different tool.

Some of your choices for tools that support float arithmetic from the command-line include:

- a different shell (eg, zsh)
- [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21806398/549246): `my $x = $minimum + rand($maximum - $minimum);`
- [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1711720/549246): `x = min + rand * (max-min)`
- [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50359625/549246):  `awk -v min=3 -v max=17 'BEGIN{srand(); print min+rand()*int(1000*(max-min)+1)/1000}'`
  *note*: [The original answer this was copied from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50359625/549246) is broken; the above is a slight modification to help correct the problem.
- [bc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/460470/19776):   `printf '%s\n' $(echo "scale=8; $RANDOM/32768" | bc )`

... to name a few.

Comment: Note that the create -> insta-delete -> edit -> undelete workflow can constitute a rule violation when done for the purpose of circumventing site rules (explicitly inclusive of the "no answering deleted questions" rule). I'm looking for the recent [meta] discussion where this came up; will link it in when I find it.

Comment: Understood.  I accidentally hit submit before I'd finished typing it up.  It won't happen again.

Comment: ...ahh, here we are: [How long is the grace period for answering closed questions and why is it only applicable to some?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402436/how-long-is-the-grace-period-for-answering-closed-questions-and-why-is-it-onl#comment805078_402450). Just an FYI, I'm not a diamond-moderator and can't enforce.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the heads up.  When I un-deleted my answer I didn't see that you'd closed it.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg  : Thank you for the answer, Ruby([e.g.](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/random-float-numbers-in-bash-871336/#post4305628)), awk worked fine for me.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg ```$ awk -v min=4 -v max=4.5 'BEGIN{srand(); print min+rand()*(max-min+1)}'
$ 5.46869
``` -> That is why (max-min + 1) will not work.

Comment: @даршан I copied that example from [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50359625/549246).  I'm not in front of a machine I can test it on to correct it.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg I have tested and also edited your answer.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg Look at the comment in the same answer that you suggested.